# Changing the Wordpress dashboard logo (multisite)

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm the superadmin for a smaller network of multisites for a client. All network sites have the same name so organizing all the sites gets a bit of a cluttered mess:

[image]

Changing the titles of each site is not an option (Since of some SEO-optimization and smiliar).

I've only found guides on how to change ALL the dashboard logos to one other (via wp_enqueue_style in functions.php), but nothing when using multisites. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This might be posible to do with CSS. 
Try to target each class, or if they all got the same class, you can use `:nth-child` operator.

```
.your-class:nth-child(1){
   // CSS to change logo
}
.your-class:nth-child(2){
   // CSS to change logo
}
.your-class:nth-child(3){
   // CSS to change logo
}
```

Below is some code for inserting css to the admin area. Place this code in the `functions.php`.

I did a test on a regular site, and it worked, but have not tested it on a multisite like yours.

Hope it works, and good luck :)

```
function custom_admin_logo() {
   echo '
   <style type="text/css">
       #wpadminbar #wp-admin-bar-wp-logo > .ab-item .ab-icon:before {
           background-image: url(' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/images/your-logo.jpg) !important;
           background-position: 0 0;
           color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
           background-size: cover;
       }
       #wpadminbar #wp-admin-bar-wp-logo.hover > .ab-item .ab-icon {
           background-position: 0 0;
       }
    </style>
    ';
}
add_action('wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'custom_admin_logo');
```